# Is it acceptable to show a QR code on a display to replace an open source license notice?

Tags: open-source

I am developing an IoT device with a small LCD display.

The device allows for a low resolution (320x240) and small storage (8~16Mb). There are limitations of the system to include open source notices and related information. (MIT, Apache 2.0)

I hope, open source notices and information are registered on the server, and the server URL link and QR Code are displayed on the screen.

I would like to know what risks, including legal issues, exist in this case.

The open source notice (MIT and Apache 2.0) does not contain any information about the notice method using URL links and QR codes. Nonetheless, I want to know if there are any legal issues.